# Issue with auto variable

Tags: c

I know about storage classes in C. I am wondering about the `auto` keyword.

In the following expression,

```
auto int i = 0;
```

`auto` is the storage class specifier, `int` is the data type.

But if we write:

```
int auto i = 0;
```

What happens? Is `auto` behaving as the data type?

Comment: Just a quick note here. No one writes "auto" or "register" in C code written in the past 20 years. Especially "auto" since it has been repurposed by C++ to mean something else.

Comment: @Art: you wish... The 15-years-old codebase on which I work every day is peppered with `register` declarations (typically in disputable places). (although I agree about `auto`, I never ever saw it in real code, even bad one)

Comment: @MatteoItalia I should have said something like "learned to program in the past 20 years", but that wouldn't be true either. I've seen freshly educated people who followed stone age practices because they learned from someone who learned "everything there is to know" in the 80s.

Comment: Please note that according to future language directions in C11, this code is poor style and should be avoided: "6.11.5 Storage-class specifiers. 
The placement of a storage-class specifier other than at the beginning of the declaration specifiers in a declaration is an obsolescent feature."

Comment: In C, `auto` is never necessary; it is always either redundant or illegal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ordering of storage class specifiers (`extern`, `static`, `register`, `auto`, `typedef`) with respect to type specifiers (`int`, `double`, `char`, etc.) does not matter. Both are valid and declare the same object.

It is, however, considered a good practice to conform to a certain order. The specifier-qualifier list which precedes the declarator (`i` in your case) consists of distinctive groups of keywords which are best used in the following order:

- Storage class specifiers, if any: `static`, `extern`, `auto`, `register`, `typedef`, `_Thread_local` (C11);
- Type qualifiers, if any: `const`, `volatile`, `restrict`;
- Type modifiers, if any: `signed`, `unsigned`, `short`, `long`;
- The type specifier: `int`, `char`, `double`, `float`, etc.

Following that rule would lead to more readable declarations like this:

```
static const volatile unsigned long int a;
```

Instead of (an extreme example):

```
unsigned volatile int static const long a;
```

Answer (score 4):

The C grammar allows you to put the storage specifier in both positions, there's no ambiguity since the intersection between the set of valid types an valid storage specifiers is empty. However, usually I've always seen the storage specifier written before the type, so you should probably stick to this convention for ease of reading by other people.

(also, avoid using `auto`, nobody ever uses it because it is always implied, to the point that C++ even repurposed that keyword for variables with inferred type)